# Associating tables in CakePHP 3 doesn't working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I try to connect two tables in my database, but I get an error message saying that there is no relation:

> Uzytkownicy is not associated with Uprawnienia

Here the code of my first model:

```
class UprawnieniaTable extends Table {
  public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->primaryKey('ID');
    $this->hasMany('Uzytkownicy', [
      'foreignKey' => 'ID_uprawnienie'
    ]);
  }
}
```

and second table:

```
class UzytkownicyTable extends Table {
  public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->belongsTo('Uprawnienia', [
      'foreignKey' => 'ID_uprawnienie'
    ]);   
  }
}
```

Table `Uzytkownicy` has a foreign key `ID_Uprawnienie`. In database everything is OK because I use this database in a normal SQL query.

Code that make error:

```
$uzytkownicy = TableRegistry::get('Uzytkownicy'); 

foreach ($uzytkownicy->find('all', ['contain' => ['Uprawnienia']]) $ uzytkownik) {
  echo $uzytkownik->imie." ".$uzytkownik->nazwisko."<br>";
  echo $uzytkownik->nazwa;
}
```

[image]

```
⟩ Cake\ORM\EagerLoader->_normalizeContain CORE/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php, line 250
⟩ Cake\ORM\EagerLoader->normalized CORE/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php, line 358
⟩ Cake\ORM\EagerLoader->attachableAssociations CORE/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php, line 337
⟩ Cake\ORM\EagerLoader->attachAssociations CORE/src/ORM/Query.php, line 897
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->_transformQuery CORE/src/ORM/Query.php, line 853
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->sql CORE/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php, line 121
⟩ Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->prepare CORE/src/Database/Connection.php, line 216
⟩ Cake\Database\Connection->prepare CORE/src/Database/Connection.php, line 268
⟩ Cake\Database\Connection->run CORE/src/Database/Query.php, line 174
⟩ Cake\Database\Query->execute CORE/src/ORM/Query.php, line 872
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->_execute CORE/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php, line 272
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->_all CORE/src/ORM/Query.php, line 823
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->all CORE/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php, line 131
⟩ Cake\ORM\Query->getIterator APP/Template/Strony/glowna.ctp, line 49
⟩ include CORE/src/View/View.php, line 971
⟩ Cake\View\View->_evaluate CORE/src/View/View.php, line 931
⟩ Cake\View\View->_render CORE/src/View/View.php, line 579
⟩ Cake\View\View->render CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 611
⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->render APP/Controller/StronyController.php, line 11
⟩ App\Controller\StronyController->pokaz [internal function]
⟩ call_user_func_array CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 429
⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction CORE/src/Routin/Dispatcher.php, line 114
⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
⟩ require ROOT/index.php, line 16
```

Comment: When receiving errors, please always include the corresponding stacktrace, and show the code that actually triggers it! That being said, why do your files (at least the first one) not have any namespace declarations?

Comment: They have namespace, I don't copy it. I want show code but I don't why  I can't edit my post. I add it now ;)

Comment: You should always include them, as they are important, and they can be a source for the problem that you are experiencing! Try `debug(get_class($uzytkownicy))` in your controller to check whether you are working with the expected class instance. You can try the same with an `Uprawnienia` table instance. ps, on a side note, it's adivsed to use english identifiers, that way it's way easier to stick to the CakePHP naming conventions, and have things like inflection work properly.

Comment: There are my namespaces form both table class `namespace App\Model\Table; use Cake\ORM\Table; ` After `debug(get_class($uzytkownicy))` I get  
`/src/Template/Strony/glowna.ctp (line 54)  
'Cake\ORM\Table'  
/src/Template/Strony/glowna.ctp (line 55)  
'Cake\ORM\Table'`

Comment: There you have it, you're operating on an auto-table, not an concrete instance of `UzytkownicyTable`. This can be because of a wrong namespace declaration, wrong filename/path, wrong file permissions, misconfigured autoloader, etc... you'll have to debug this further. Also check Debug Kits SQL Log panel, it will list all auto generated models in the current request.